# django drf not listing all data in models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am testing to overwrite the object with same "user" value after posting the data, the django model is like below:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Customer Name", help_text="Customer Name")
    account = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Account Id", help_text="Account Id")
    role = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="customer Role", help_text="IAM Role")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="User Name", help_text="User Name")
    post_time = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name="Post Time", help_text="Post Time", null=True)
```

Serializer class:

````
    """
    TestModel Serializer
    """

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = '__all__'```


        def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.get('user')
        try:
            testobj = TestModel.objects.get(user=user)
            for key, value in validated_data.items():
                setattr(testobj, key, value)
            testobj.save()
            return testobj
        except TestModel.DoesNotExist:
            return super().create(validated_data)
````

Viewset:

```
class TestViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  
    lookup_field = 'user'
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class =  TestModelSerializer
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
```

Every time after post, the database record updated as expected, but when accessing via get api and using the user as lookup_field, it always return the stale(the old record values).

Appreciate for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems cache is the reason...

Answer (score 1):

In certain circumstances, Django Rest Framework uses cache as well as Django. Override the `get_queryset` method on the `TestViewSet` class to retrieve the data from the database instead of the cache.

For example:

```py
class TestViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  
    lookup_field = 'user'
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class =  TestModelSerializer
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()

    # added
    def get_queryset(self):
        return TestModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a decorator to avoid caching response for the TestViewset class.

Comment: Thanks. I used a decorator to avoid caching response for the TestViewset class.

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control


@method_decorator(cache_control(no_cache=True), name='dispatch')
class TestViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
Is this working the same?